# add extra legend to plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Hi can I add an additional legend to a ggplot.
Like
the following code

```
d <- melt(as.matrix(data.frame(y1=1/(1:10),y2=1/(10:1))))
ggplot(d, aes(x=Var1, y=value,fill=Var2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge')
```

This generates a nice legend containing the name of my dataframe.
But is it possible to put in an extralegend, that contains some extra information generated from the data.

In the standard R, I would add the additional legend like

```
d<-data.frame(y1=1/(1:10),y2=2*1/(10:1))
barplot(t(d),beside=T)
legend("top",paste("sums:",apply(d,2,sum)))
```

Thanks

Comment: you could add some text with `annotate`, in the plot panel, or with `grid.text` anywhere on the device window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me.

```
    plot.new()
    d <- melt(as.matrix(data.frame(y1=1/(1:10),y2=1/(10:1))))
    ggplot(d, aes(x=Var1, y=value,fill=Var2)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge')
```

then the exciting stuff.

```
  legend('top',paste("sums:",tapply(d$value,d$Var2,sum)))
```

I changed the apply statement to work on the molten data.

I am not aware of a ggplot solution, but I would love to see one.

Comment: I can't make the second part working with your example legend('top',paste("sums:",tapply(d$value,d$Var2,sum)))
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the above post to call 'plot.new()' first

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware that I could juse base graphics on ggplot, just by calling plot.new first

Comment: If you change the coordinates of the legend you will see the big drawback of this method.